# ImportError: No module named 'pyrebase'

Tags: python, firebase, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on a project with my raspberry pi. In this project I want to connect my raspberry to google firebase, therefore I have to use:

```
import pyrebase
```

I have installed pyrebase in terminal with:

```
pip install pyrebase
```

Also I'm aware that pyrebase doesn't support python 2, so i'm using python 3.4.2. I don't know why python can't find it, any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: If pip was successful installing, it should be listed in the output of `pip freeze`, do you not see `pyrebase` in the output? Also did you install pip with python 3.4.2?

Comment: @downshift I don't see pyrebase listed by pip freeze, so i guess it is not properly installed. Do you know how to resolve this problem and i'm also not sure if i installed it for 3.4.2 I just did like i said bevore pip install pyrebase. A lot of thanks in advance.

Comment: according to the [python 3.4.2 docs](http://docs.python.org/3.4/installing/#install-scientific-python-packages) you should be able to explicitly point that python version and use its `pip` command, to see if `pip` is installed to that version of python, 3.4.2, depending on what platform you're using..[the raspberrypi website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md) says to use something like  `pip3 install <package>` installs packages for "python 3" whereas `pip` installs modules for "python 2", so maybe try `pip3 install pyrebase`

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple versions of python installed, it may be confused on which version of pyrebase to install.

Try:

```
pip3 install pyrebase
```

Comment: It worked for me. It's quite obvious, but you should add sudo first. `sudo pip3 install pyrebase`

Answer (score 2):

Try to import like this:

```
from pyrebase import pyrebase
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This will work on latest versions of python

```
pip install pyrebase4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pip3 install pyrebase4
```

if this doesn't work
write this:

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

then

```
pip install pyrebase
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the pip you're using is working with your python version

```
pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Mine is working with python 2.7.
If you're working with the right python version try pip freeze or pip list to see the list of currently installed libraries, and check if the one that you're trying to install is there.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Option is to install Ubuntu Mate in your raspberry pi as i have tried this on debian and got the same problem for absolutely no reason!! so i installed ubuntu mate and here you go it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pyrebase <br>
```

This is for python 2.x
Please install python 3.x and pip3.x instead, then run

```
`pip3.x install pyrebase`
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the `"import error"` of `pyrebase`. After checking this link I got the idea of problem, but was unable to find proper solution. After struggling for a day, I got the Solution. As I was using `PYREBASE` for my Engineering Project, I re-installed `RASPBIAN-JESSIE` stretch image on SD. Removed `python2.7` and `python3` and again installed `python3` and then installing `pyrebase` and with frequent reboots. but it worked!

```
$ sudo apt-get remove python2.7

$ sudo apt-get remove python3

$ sudo reboot

$ sudo apt-get install python3

$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

$ sudo python3 get-pip.py

$ pip3 freeze      #(displays about 15 lines, if pip is installed correctly) 

$ pip3 list        #(displays about 15 lines)

$ sudo pip3 install pyrebase
```

and now,

from `pyrebase import pyrebase`

and it did not gave import error.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons pyrebase Lib will only works in **pycharm** ide.

[donwload Pycharm IDE Here !](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/)

1- Start Clean:

```
pip3 uninstall pyrebase4

pip3 uninstall pyrebase
```

2- Install Lib

```
pip3 install pyrebase
```

3- Restart your PC.

4- Run **pycharm** ide as administrator

5- Import it in Python:

```
from pyrebase import pyrebase
```

You should have it to work now!

Comment: thats not ideal because the original pyrebase github is not being mantained anymore. pyrebase4 has already a few fixes